# Allocated bytes in Java applications

Tags: java, memory-management, allocation

Is there a way of finding how many bytes were allocated in a Java application? If possible, without changing the code?
Thanks.

Comment: many discussions about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785290/java-unit-testing-how-to-measure-memory-footprint-for-method-call http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536149/best-way-to-measure-memory-usage-of-a-java-program http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21272877/understanding-jvm-memory-allocation-and-java-out-of-memory-heap-space

Comment: By "allocated in a Java application", can you clarify a little?  Do you mean total memory usage within the VM environment, or something else?

Comment: yes, I mean total memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

for example, from this post:
[Java unit testing: how to measure memory footprint for method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785290/java-unit-testing-how-to-measure-memory-footprint-for-method-call)

Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();

Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();

Answer (score 1):

You can use several available methods in java.lang.Runtime [1] class or (more sophisticated) JMX [2]

[1] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html
[2] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/overview/javavm.html